# Intersection of four circles

Tags: graphics

I would really appreciate it if someone would be able to help me generate the following figure in Mathematica.

[image: image to be replicated]

This is what I have started with:

```
redius = 6;
center = 3;
font = 15;

Graphics[{
  Circle[{-center, -center}, redius], 
  Circle[{-center, center}, redius], 
  Circle[{center, -center}, redius], 
  Circle[{center, center}, redius],
  Black, Text[Style["Technical Tools", FontSize -> font], {-redius, center + 2}],
  Black, Text[Style["Human \n Aspect", FontSize -> font], {center + 1, redius + 1}],
  Black, Text[Style["Mental \n Process", FontSize -> font], {-redius, -redius + 1}], ,
  Black, Text[Style["Paperwork \n Process", FontSize -> font], {redius, -center - 1}]
}]
```

and I have been able to generate the following figure.

[image: my best attempt]

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: `With[{a = 0.5, r = 1},
 Graphics[{
   EdgeForm[
    Black], {Opacity[0.2, #[[1]]], 
      Disk[#[[2]], r], {Opacity[1, Black], 
       Text[Style[#[[3]], Bold], 1.75 #[[2]]]}} & /@
    {{Red, {-a, 
       a}, "Technical\nTools"},
     {Blue, {a, a}, "Human\nAspect"}, {Orange, {a, -a}, 
      "Mental\nProcess"}, {Green, {-a, -a}, "Paperwork\nProcess"}},
   Opacity[1, Black],
   Text[Style["Education", Bold], {0, 0}]}]]`

Comment: @ Bob, your comment is more than an answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
SeedRandom[1234]
colors = RandomColor[4];
centers = Tuples[{-1, 1}/2, {2}];

Graphics[MapThread[{Opacity[.5], #, EdgeForm[{Darker@#, Thick}], Translate[Disk[], #2]} &, 
   {colors, centers}]]
```

[image]

```
colors = {Red, Green, Blue, Yellow};
labels = {"Paperwork Process", "MentalProcess", "Human Aspect", "Technical Tools"};


Graphics[{MapThread[{EdgeForm[{Darker@#, Thick}], #, Translate[Disk[], #2], 
  Text[Style[#3, 14, FontOpacity -> 1, FontColor -> Black], {4, 3} #2], 
  Arrowheads[Medium], Black, Arrow[{{4, 2.75} #2, {3, 2} #2}]} &, 
  {colors, centers, labels}], 
 Opacity[1], Text[Style["Education", 14], {0, 0}]}, 
 ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

Comment: I really appreciate it, kglr. This was what I was looking for. Thank you so much

Comment: @DLT, my pleasure. Thank you for the accept.

Answer (score 5):

The midpoints of the four circles(radius r) lie on a square(sidelength a)
Change `Circle` to `Disk` to get colored circles.

```
With[{a = 0.5, r = 1}, Graphics[{ EdgeForm[Black], Opacity[.2],
FaceForm[Blue], Disk[{a, a}, r], Circle[{-a, a}, r],Circle[{-a, -a}, r] , Circle[{ a, -a}, r]}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Ulrich but I also need different colors and texts as well as shown in the figure.

Comment: Change `Circle` to `Disk`. `FaceForm[color]` changes the color. See my edit.